# Are these spots on my office plant bad?

Tags: houseplants, office-gardening

[image]

Are those spots on my plant at my desk at work anything to worry about?

Comment: there are some tiny white specks, as Stormy says in a comment below - but if its whitefly, you can check by giving the plant a little shake - they should rise up in a sort of cloud....they seem to be on leaves attached to that yellowed stem, centre of the plant, but I'm not sure from the image. Check the whole plant closely...

Comment: @Bamboo I have tried to do that little shake and I have not seen this little cloud ever happen.  I am quite disappointed!  Maybe the leaves get so sticky over time with honey dew that the white fly are able to stay stuck to the leaf and can survive weird earthquakes?  Grin!

Comment: @stormy you've obviously found nymphs rather than adults then - adults will fly up if you blow on the plant, if they're present, though to be fair, they usually are present if there are nymphs

Comment: That's partly true.  There are always different generations going on when I've taken the time to look with my trusty little loop.  Maybe my eyesight is so bad I've never seen them flying?  I see 'em I neem 'em...well, depending on the plant and timing.  They loved my peppers last year and I had tons of peppers coming on and the leaves were peppered with white fly.  Lots of flowers.  So I just let it go.  Gooey, sticky leaves.  Great harvest of peppers out of 4 and some 6 inch pots.  But although I know that they fly up when shaken they've never done it in front of me, sigh.

Comment: @stormy - just be grateful - its horrible being enveloped in a cloud of whitefly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plant appears to be Zamioculcus zamiifolia (more easily known as ZZ plant). These dark blotches or spots are quite normal and nothing to worry about - they develop on older stems. The stem I'm uncertain about is the more yellowish coloured stem with blotches in the forefront of the picture, that one might have a problem, because of its yellowish colour rather than the blotches, although the  leaves coming off it look perfectly healthy. If the leaves start to turn yellow, then clip that stem out and adjust your watering as described below, if that's not how you're watering currently.

Getting the watering right is important - they need to dry out a  little between waterings, so water when the surface of the potting soil feels just dry to the touch, water well, and empty out any excess from an outer pot or tray 30 minutes  later. They tolerate various light conditions, but prefer relatively bright light, though never direct sunlight, and temperatures between 13-26 deg C. Usually, overwatering shows itself by yellowing leaves rather than a yellowing stem; the colour of that stem may not be particularly significant, though the need for repotting might be a possibility, I'm unable to tell because the pot is not visible in the photo. More information here https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/zzplant

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I am seeing something different that might have been misconstrued. John, what blotches were you meaning?  I see white fly on the undersides of your leaves, easy to control but necessary to control.  I distinctly see white insects in the shadows of the leaves in the center of this picture.  Is that what you meant?  @John ?

Comment: Is then Araucaria araucana known as AA plant? There should be an expression 'from Araucaria araucana to Zamioculcus zamifolia'...

Comment: @stormy - well spotted - I had to magnify twice in order to see those flecks! I think I need new specs...

Comment: @stormy i’ll double check when I get back to work on Monday, but no I don’t think those are bugs on the leaves. I think it’s just how my phone took the photo. However I was referring to the blotches on the stem.

Comment: @Bamboo I imagine you using magnifying glasses in front of your monitor...

Comment: @Stormy Can you perhaps see in the photo if the white flies are european, hell bent to invade native american plants?

Comment: @VividD  nope, tablet, no monitor, and it magnifies as much as its possible  on screen, no need for separate kit...  but I do need stronger specs, just waiting for eye surgery first...

Comment: @VividD is showing a bad boy? streak, Bamboo!  I used to have 20/15 vision and now I use 3 or 4 pairs, wearing on my head even coupling and overlapping to get better closeups.  Not wearing sunglasses...not good.  Crispy eyes.

Comment: I didn't think at first that the dark splotches were what you meant...they are normal...the white specks are not and I can't think of another reason for them to be in the picture, in the shadows other than WHITE really stands out in the shadows and well.  When you get back, use a magnifying glass and I'll bet you've got white fly.  Not a big deal but one that should be addressed sooner than later.  A good reason for the blotchiness on the leaves that you can see the light coming through the backside...showing thinning areas that have been sucked dry by white fly.  Or some sucking insect.

Answer (score 5):

The whitish spots look like pesticide residue to me. This is most likely on a new plant.  One of the last things the growers do before shipping is an application of pesticide to take of insect pests. It could also be dissolved salts from alkaline water.

Take a cloth and rub the leaves, if it comes off it is a residue. Wash your hands afterwards in case they used something with residual activity.

Otherwise your plant looks very healthy